# Javascript Promise then and fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
$http.post('/api/APICall', JSON.stringify($scope.saveData)).then(function (data) {

});
```

Which works, but how would I add a section if the API fails?

I have tried the following:

```
$http.post('/api/APICall', JSON.stringify($scope.saveData)).then(function (data) {

    })
.fail(function (err) {
            alert("An Error has occured, please contact support to resolve.");
        });
```

But I get this error:

> $http.post(...).then(...).fail is not a function

Comment: [Is the documentation for a Promise not specific enough?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: [Good reading about chaining .then() and .catch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619444/chaining-promises-with-then-and-catch)

Comment: Is `$http` from Angular? If so, why is this question tagged jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you pass your fail callback as the second argument to then():

```
$http.post('/api/APICall', JSON.stringify($scope.saveData))
.then(
  function (data) {
   // success
  },
  function (data) {
   // error
  }
);
```