# if an error is thrown at some point in a promise chain, is it automatically propagated all the way down the chain?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

Say you have a promise chain like this:

```
asyncFunction()
.then((value) => {
    resolve(value)
})
.then((value) => {
    resolve(value)
})
.then((value) => {
    resolve(value)
})
.catch((error) => {
    reject(error)
})
```

If an error is thrown during one of those function calls, does that error automatically propagate all the way down to the `catch` at the end of the chain? Say the error is thrown at the beginning, during `asyncFunction()`, what are the exact mechanics of how it propagates? Is the error passed to the handler of each `then`? Or does each then look for a second handler, not see one, and so pass the error to the next `then`?

Comment: The error is caught by the next `catch` block in the chain.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Please avoid the [explicit construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Processing errors in promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879655/processing-errors-in-promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will get propagated down until it hits the first `catch`. All `then` clauses should be skipped.

I noticed the use of `resolve()` and `reject()` avoid this, there's no need for the Promise constructor pattern in case like this.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) when you say it gets propagated to the next catch, you mean if an error is thrown, it just skips the `then`s? And 2) I don't understand what you mean about resolve and reject. Could you elaborate?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) The resolve() and reject() functions suggest that you wrapped this in `new Promise()`. You don't need to do this. Just return the chain from the function instead of a 'new promise'.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: the fact that resolve and reject are available implies the whole code block is wrapped in `new Promise()`, right? So the alternative is to not wrap it in `new Promise()`, and instead to do `return value` instead of `resolve value`?

Comment: Yes, that was my guess! And yes the alternative is to use `return asyncFunction.then(...etc...)`

Comment: What I meant was, where I now have `resolve(value)` etc, use `return(value)`?

Comment: Your code does not really make sense, because you don't want to call resolve() multiple times. But yes, the thing you want to return from main function should be returned in the last step.