# how to execute three asynchronous functions one after one

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, functional-programming

i apologize if it is already asked but i have searched all over the internet and nothing has worked 
i am working with firestore and javascript
i have tried this by far & a lot of other things

```
var App

  function A (){

    firebase.database().ref('Info/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
      var Ipz = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().Iplist) || 'Anonymous';
      console.log(Ipz)
     })

    console.log('A')
   }


   function B (){
    console.log('B')
   }


      App = Promise.resolve();

      App = App.then(A).then(B);

      App.then(() => {
      console.log("All done");
        })
```

my output :-

```
A
B
All done
JdGJtwEe8rb394BlX4IkjUfH4Wv1;JdGJtwEe8rb394BlX4IkjUfH4Wv1;
```

while i want this output

```
JdGJtwEe8rb394BlX4IkjUfH4Wv1;JdGJtwEe8rb394BlX4IkjUfH4Wv1;
A
B
All done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining promises with then and catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619444/chaining-promises-with-then-and-catch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to chain the asynchronous database function with the `A`, `B`, and `all done` functions using `.then` to connect each one:

```
function lookup() {
  return firebase.database().ref('Info/').once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var Ipz = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().Iplist) || 'Anonymous';
      console.log(Ipz)
      // if you want to pass Ipz to `A` as a parameter, then `return Ipz;` here
    });
}
function A() {
  console.log('A');
}
function B() {
  console.log('B');
}
lookup()
  .then(A)
  .then(B)
  .then(() => console.log("All done"));
```