# How to find out the fetch ReadableStream is closed by error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have this code:

```
fetch('endpoint_url')
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then((response) => {
    const reader = response.getReader();

    reader.read()
      .then(({ done, value }) => {
        if (done) {
          console.log('DONE');
          return;
        }

       // use value
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Failed');
      });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Failed');
  });
```

After a while reading data, I get `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200`.
I searched about it and people say it's a chrome issue with some antiviruses, but I'm using OSX and no antivirus.

Anyway, my problem is I want to catch the error and react to it, but none of the `console.log()`s works.

Any idea on how I should do this?

Comment: Would be helpful to be able to reproduce the same Error... Won't be easy though. So none of your catch works? Once it happened next calls to `reader.read()` should throw no? What does the last value contain?

Comment: @Kaiido Nothing. It just stop working and just an error on console of chrome

Comment: @Kaiido actually the reader called its catch. Sometimes after a while. So the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To print the message of an error, you first need to catch it.

instead of

```
.catch(() => {
    console.log('Failed');
});
```

do

```
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('Failed: ' + e.message);
});
```

That will give you the message of error you encountered.

Note that:

> Any given exception will be caught only once by the nearest enclosing
>   catch-block unless it is re-thrown. Of course, any new exceptions
>   raised in the "inner" block (because the code in catch-block may do
>   something that throws), will be caught by the "outer" block.

Comment: None of the `console.log()`s work. It means none of the catches called. So I think the problem is something else.

Comment: @SinaMirhejazi So you never even get to call catch? It doesn't even log "Failed"?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the error, since it's happening in the fetch.

Try:

```
fetch('endpoint_url')
 .then(response => response.body)
 .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

but I'm not convinced by the structure of your code anyway. Look here for further analysis:

[Chaining promises with then and catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619444/chaining-promises-with-then-and-catch)

Comment: I believe I have a catch on `fetch`.